# Why is a mocked jest promise not rejected with allSettled?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-promise

I want to test a method which returns the result of [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) and calls another function which returns promises.

I reduced the problem to the following test code:

```
  describe('Promise tests', () => {
    it('should reject directly', async () => {
      const f = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error('foo'));
      const p = async () => await f();

      // works
      await expect(p).rejects.toThrow('foo');
    });

    it('should reject with allSettled', async () => {
      const f = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error('foo'));
      const p = async () => await f();

      const results = await Promise.allSettled([p]);
      expect(results[0].status).toBe('rejected'); // fulfilled - but why?
      expect(results[0].reason).toBe('foo');
    });
  });
```

Why is the second case not receiving a rejected promise?

- node.js v14.3.0
- jest v25.4.0

Comment: Your first test case fails for me: `expect(p)` vs. `expect(p())`. As `p` is returning a promise, Promise.allSettled should look like this: `Promise.allSettled([p(), /* many more*/])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. `Promise.allSettled` expects to receive an array of Promises not an array of functions returning a promise, which in fact is what your constant `p` does.

By simply calling the `p()` you solve your issue:

```js
  describe('Promise tests', () => {
    it('should reject directly', async () => {
      const f = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error('foo'));
      const p = async () => await f();

      // works
      await expect(p()).rejects.toThrow('foo');
    });

    it('should reject with allSettled', async () => {
      const f = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error('foo'));
      const p = async () => await f();

      const results = await Promise.allSettled([p()]);
      expect(results[0].status).toBe('rejected'); // fulfilled - but why?
      expect(results[0].reason).toBe('foo');
    });
  });
```

*By the way*: My linter complains about unnecessary awaits :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, got it! My first case still passes, though. I'll also check what rules I need to add to eslint/recommended (plus TypeScript)