# Test Promise.allSettled using Jest does not work

Tags: node.js, promise, jestjs

Does Jest allow spying or mocking a method that is called within Promise.allSettled?

Here is my sample code index.js

```
exports.handleMessage = async () => {
let messages = [{"body":"something"},{"body": "something"}];
Promise.allSettled(messages.map(processMessage));
return;
}

const processMessage = aysnc (message) => {
  //do something
  return;
}
exports.processMessage = processMessage;
```

Test code

```
const {handleMessage, processMessage} = require('index.js');

jest.mock("index.js", () => {
    const original = jest.requireActual("index.js"); 
    return {
        ...original,
        processMessage: jest.fn()
    };
});

  describe("test methods", () => {
    test("test", async () => {
      processMessage.mockImplementation(() => {return;});
      await handleMessages();
      expect(processMessage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    });
});
```

When I run the test, it does not call the mocked method but actual implementation.

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 2
    Received number of calls: 0

      227 |
      228 |       await handleMessages();
    > 229 |       expect(processMessage).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
          |                            ^
      230 |     });
      231 |   });
      232 | });
```

Planning to change it to a async loop, but it would be great to have it tested with Promise.allSettled. Any suggestions?

Comment: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580885/why-is-a-mocked-jest-promise-not-rejected-with-allsettled) that could solve your problem.